# Crystal reports fiel value only one time apperance

Tags: crystal-reports

hi everyone good people,
Have a question regarding crystal report which i'm populating by data. My question is how to for each section of data records only for particular field to show only value once if there will be more than one record. What i tried was to check 'Suppress Duplication' and in this case it's as i wanted to have but problem is if value is same in other section it will be not shown. How to do it? Hope you get the point.

Added example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJgeB.png)

Comment: Your issue was not clear... can you show sample data?

Comment: see main post again. If you look i ad some data - i marked section of rows for you. In this case all sections has 2 rows (could be also more/less). As you see at the beggining its like it should be there are values and for next records for each sections is blank - ok. In last section is something strange i dont get as there should be also value 1212,12 but first record is empty... I dont know why. Currently the Preis field has Format Object --> Supress duplicates option checked.

Comment: I don't think it because of supress option because section 2 also has same data check if data is retriving from database.

Comment: so where could be wrong?

Comment: Can you check if the query retrieving the data for the required combination....I guess data itself is not being retrieved from database